# How to connect different variables from different controllers whit the same id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with diferrent controllers. One controller has a variable called permissions and the other as a variable called communications. The communications variable as a communications_id and the permissions variable has a communications_id parameter as well, but i dont know how to connect them. I need to collect the information to show only the communications that have the same communications_id as the permissions  on a communications board. Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the requirement with your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.